# Interface with List of same interface

Tags: c#, .net, interface

I have the following interface:

```
public interface IObject{
double x {get;}
double y {get;}
List<IObject> List{get; set;}
}
```

and this class

```
public class Holder<T> where T : IObject {
private T myItem;
public void ChangeItemList(T item){
myItem.List = item.List;
}
```

However the compiler doesn't like the ChangeItemList method and on this line :

```
myItem.List = item.List;
```

gives me this error:

```
Cannot convert source type 'List<T>' to target type 'List<IObject>'
```

Why can't I do it and what is a good solution for this scenario?
thank you

Comment: You cannot possibly have that interface because interfaces cannot contain fields. This code won't compile.

Comment: You seem to have member fields in your interface. This is not permitted. double x; and double y; cannot be declared in an interface.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: sorry they were supposed to  be properties. I edited my code.

Comment: why not: public void ChangeItemList(IObject item)?

Comment: You have something wrong in other places. The code (after removing unnecessary semicolons) compiles fine. Are you sure your interface is not generic as well?

Comment: because I don't want to allow to pass any IObject, only the generic type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you want to achieve but the following compiles and runs without exceptions:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var holder = new Holder<IObject>();
        holder.MyItem = new Object { List = new List<IObject>() };
        holder.ChangeItemList(new Object { List = new List<IObject>() });
    }
}

public class Object : IObject
{
    public List<IObject> List { get; set; }
}

public interface IObject
{
    List<IObject> List { get; set; }
}

public class Holder<T> where T : IObject
{
    public T MyItem { get; set; }

    public void ChangeItemList(T item)
    {
        MyItem.List = item.List;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this one- worked for me. The problem i had that myItem was null.

```
public class Holder<T> where T : IObject
{
    private T myItem = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();

    public void ChangeItemList(T item)
    {
        myItem.List = item.List;
    }
}
```